# Qual é a diferença entre Cubos, Datasets e Tabelas?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Sou iniciante no mundo de dados e tenho dificuldade de entender a diferença entre um Cubo, um Dataset e uma Tabela.

Já estudei sobre modelos multidimensionais Star-Schemas e Snow Flake e sei que, no primeiro, uma tabela fato está relacionada a pelo menos 2 tabelas de dimensões e que, no segundo, uma tabela fato está relacionada a pelo menos 2 tabelas de dimensões e que pelo menos 1 dessas tabelas de dimensões deve estar relacionada a uma terceira tabela de dimensão.

Até aí, ok, porém, o que diferencia isso de um Cubo? Eu posso chamar isso de Cubo? E também posso chamar de Dataset? Ambos são a mesma coisa? E uma tabela, ela pode ser um Cubo ou um Dataset? Enfim, são muitas palavrinhas que pra mim parecem ser a mesma coisa, mas não tenho certeza se são.

Comment: Creio que este post pode te ajudar a entender melhor https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-data-cube-and-relational-tables